# Python3, ctypes API and Enum

Tags: python-3.x, enums, callback, prototype, ctypes

It seems i cannot instantiate a ctypes.CFUNCTYPE prototype with an Enum return value even when the Enum contains the classmethod `from_param`.
Anybody experienced that?
Is there a workaround, maybe?
Did i do something wrong?

This works:

```
import ctypes as ct

@ct.CFUNCTYPE(ct.c_int, ct.c_int)
def pyfunc(a):
    return 100

print(pyfunc(10))
```

> 100

This works, too (linux):

```
import ctypes as ct
import enum


class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
    A = 1
    B = 2

    @classmethod
    def from_param(cls, param):
        return ct.c_int(param)


printf = ct.CDLL("libc.so.6").printf
printf.restype = MyEnum  
printf(b"1")
```

> <MyEnum.A: 1>

```
printf(b"12")
```

> <MyEnum.B: 2>

This fails:

```
import ctypes as ct
import enum

class E(enum.Enum):
    A = 10
   
    @classmethod
    def from_param(cls, param):
        return ct.c_int(param)

 @ct.CFUNCTYPE(E, ct.c_int)
 def pyfunc(a):
     return E(10)
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
>     @ct.CFUNCTYPE(E, ct.c_int)
> TypeError: invalid result type for callback function
> ```

Comment: You need to use `IntEnum`, but depending on how ctytpes treats its arguments that still may not work.

Comment: I tried that out -> That gives me exacly the same result

Comment: Why do you need the callback function to return an *enum* value? Why not simply return an *int* and cast it to *enum* as the last step?

Comment: Because i know what mess a code can be if everything is int instead of some proper type

Comment: That is true. Hmm, from the above example it's not clear where does *C* come into play.

Comment: It is a mock function i use in my unit tests.

Comment: How are you calling `pyfunc` in your unit tests?   Directly from Python or as used in a real C function as a callback?   C can't receive a Python Enum.  Use `ct.c_int` for the return type and `return E.A.value`.  Also, the docs only mention `from_param` being called for arguments types, not return types, and in my experimentation that appears to be true.  While you can assign a `.restype` of `E` to a function, it is still an integer as returned from C.

Comment: That's not at all true. I added a working example, that ctypes api is indeed able to convert an c_int returned by a c function call into an appropriate Enum member. When i define a CFUNCTYPE prototype and instatiante it, the behaviour is completely unorthogonal ! The printf example is a little bit silly, but it shows what i mean. Imagine, instead of printf we call some c func which returns an enumerated error code. It was just a welcome printf property that i could specify the return value by passing an input string with a length of the desired return value.

Comment: Your added example doesn't work for me.  I get `1`, *not* `<MyEnum.A: 1>`.  Did you forget to paste some lines?

Comment: Ah, I added `printf.restype = MyEnum` and now I see your results.

Comment: Yeah, i forgot that. Updated question. Nice that you come to the same result.

Comment: `from_param` is not being called in your new example.  I was using `print` to see if `from_param` was called.  Delete the `from_param` class method and it still works.  In fact I just made a basic class that has an `__init__` method that takes one parameter and assigning `.restype` to that class calls `__init__` with the return value, so any Python type can be used as a `.restype` if it takes a one parameter for `__init__`.  It still makes sense that `CFUNCTYPE` can't take anything but a `ctypes` type for *its* return value since normally the value is being returned to a C function.

Comment: I've found out that i can workaround the default behaviour by changing the `.restype` to `E` after the declaration of `pyfunc` or don't use @wrapper syntax at all and instead create and instantiate prototype manually and then change the `.restype` of the instantiation. As my pyfunc won't be called from C this should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues here:

- the return value of `pyfunc` is going back to a C routine, so must be a standard ctypes type (`E` is not a ctype type)
- neither `from_param` nor `_as_parameter_` appear to be called for a return type

To address these problems you must

- change the `E` in `@ct.CFUNCTYPE` to `ct.c_int`

and one of the following:

- use `IntEnum` instead of `Enum`

or

- return `E(a).value`

or

- add `__int__` and `__index__` to your enum (which makes it `int`-like enough for `ctypes`):

```
    class E(enum.Enum):
        A = 10
        #
        def __int__(self):
            return self.value
        __index__ = __int__
```

Comment: "the return value of pyfunc is going [,,,]" -> No, the return value of the pyfunc callee is going back to a python caller.   "neither from_param nor _as_parameter_ [...]" -> See my added example that ctypes can indeed convert c_int return values in Enum members.

Comment: @pqans but normally a `CFUNCTYPE`-wrapped function is called by a C caller, and it wouldn't be able to handle a Python Enum object.  If you are calling it with a Python caller, then don't decorate it with `CFUNCTYPE`.

Comment: If it does not behave as the original c function it's not a proper mock for unit testing. But now i understand why the CFUNCTYPE behaves in this way.